# Struct of arrays, arrays of structs and memory usage pattern

Tags: c, arrays, struct, cpu-cache

I've been reading about SOA and I wanted to try an implement it in a system that I am building up.

I am writing some simple C struct to do some tests but I am a bit confused, right now I have 3 different struct for a `vec3`. I will show them below and then go into further details about the question.

```
struct vec3
{
size_t x, y, z;
};

struct vec3_a
{
size_t pos[3];
};

struct vec3_b
{
size_t* x;
size_t* y;
size_t* z;
};

struct vec3 vec3(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    struct vec3 v;
    v.x = x;
    v.y = y;
    v.z = z;
    return v;
}

struct vec3_a vec3_a(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    struct vec3_a v;
    v.pos[0] = x;
    v.pos[1] = y;
    v.pos[2] = z;
    return v;
}

struct vec3_b vec3_b(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    struct vec3_b v;
    v.x = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    v.y = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    v.z = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t));
    *(v.x) = x;
    *(v.y) = y;
    *(v.z) = z;
    return v;
}
```

That's the declarations of the three types of vec3.

```
struct vec3 v = vec3(10, 20, 30);
struct vec3_a va = vec3_a(10, 20, 30);
struct vec3_b vb = vec3_b(10, 20, 30);
```

Printing out the addresses with printf I get values like these:

```
size of vec3      : 24 bytes
size of vec3a     : 24 bytes
size of vec3b     : 24 bytes
size of size_t    : 8 bytes
size of int       : 4 bytes
size of 16 int    : 64 bytes
vec3 x:10, y:20, z:30
vec3 x:0x7fff57f8e788, y:0x7fff57f8e790, z:0x7fff57f8e798
vec3a x:10, y:20, z:30
vec3a x:0x7fff57f8e768, y:0x7fff57f8e770, z:0x7fff57f8e778
vec3b x:10, y:20, z:30
vec3b x:0x7fbe514026a0, y:0x7fbe51402678, z:0x7fbe51402690
```

One final thing that I did was create an array of 10 struct `vec3_b` and printed out the addresses which returned these values.

```
    struct vec3_b vb3[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        vb3[i] = vec3_b(i, i*2, i*4);
    }

index:0 vec3b x:0x7fbe514031f0, y:0x7fbe51403208, z:0x7fbe51403420
index:1 vec3b x:0x7fbe51403420, y:0x7fbe51403438, z:0x7fbe51403590
index:2 vec3b x:0x7fbe51403590, y:0x7fbe514035a8, z:0x7fbe514035c0
index:3 vec3b x:0x7fbe514035c0, y:0x7fbe514035d8, z:0x7fbe514035f0
index:4 vec3b x:0x7fbe514035f0, y:0x7fbe51403608, z:0x7fbe51403680
index:5 vec3b x:0x7fbe51403680, y:0x7fbe51403698, z:0x7fbe514036b0
index:6 vec3b x:0x7fbe514036b0, y:0x7fbe514036c8, z:0x7fbe514036e0
index:7 vec3b x:0x7fbe514036e0, y:0x7fbe514036f8, z:0x7fbe51403710
index:8 vec3b x:0x7fbe51403710, y:0x7fbe51403728, z:0x7fbe51403740
index:9 vec3b x:0x7fbe51403740, y:0x7fbe51403758, z:0x7fbe51403770
```

Questions:

1. Is my implementation of `struct vec3_b` the proper way to setup a struct of array?
2. Since the `vec_3b` structure is 24 bytes large, I could fit 2 plus 12 additional bytes in 1 modern cpu's cache line?
3. If my `vec3_b` is the proper way to do a SoA setup, I am having some trouble with the addressing, where I put 10 vec3_b together.

Looking at the hex values and their decimal representations I cannot see any pattern which leads me to believe that my setup is incorrect.

```
      ---------------x-----------------|----------------y-----------------|----------------z-----------------|

0|    0x7fbe514031f0 : 140455383675376 | 0x7fbe51403208 : 140455383675400 | 0x7fbe51403420 : 140455383675936
1|    0x7fbe51403420 : 140455383675936 | 0x7fbe51403438 : 140455383675960 | 0x7fbe51403590 : 140455383676304
2|    0x7fbe51403590 : 140455383676304 | 0x7fbe514035a8 : 140455383676328 | 0x7fbe514035c0 : 140455383676352
```

Comment: You have a memory leak problem with `vec_b`, since there are `malloc()` calls and there are no `free()` calls.

Comment: @llya I didn't put that part of the code in here but along with Jonathan's answer below that's also another reason not to use this type of setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I can't think of an occasion when `vec_3b` would be a good idea.
2. Note that you also have to find space for 24 bytes of data for the pointers to point at, and it probably won't be contiguous with the structure itself, so you have probably just reduced your effective cache size by a factor of 2 compared to `vec3` or `vec_3a`.  Each `malloc()` has a minimum size; on a 64-bit machine, that is usually at least 16 bytes.  So three separate allocations for the three pointed at values in a `vec_3b` structure needs at least 48 other bytes for the supporting data (plus the 24 for the structure itself).  That doesn't fit in a single cache line; it's not guaranteed to be placed so that it fits into 2 cache lines.
3. N/A — the question is predicated on a false assumption.

Comment: you're right about the allocating space for the pointers, I wasn't even thinking about that when I was writing up these tests. That would explain why the memory had no pattern at all. I am trying to define data structures that would fit in nicely with simd types. I will update the question with more information and see if I can refine this down to something that works, I don't mind rotating my data to fit but as you can see I wasn't successful in my first attempt.

Comment: On the whole, it would be better to leave this question as it is and ask a new one for your revised scenario.  Otherwise, you have a chameleon question, which is not looked upon kindly.

Comment: my apologizes, i'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

1 & 3: No, your `vec3_b` is *not* a struct-of-arrays setup.

What you're doing is having multiple structs, each with a 64bit pointer to 64bits of data.

With struct-of-arrays, you make ONE struct, and it has a few arrays of variable size.

So the 10th x value would be `mystruct.x[9]`, not `mystruct[9].x[0]`.

The key point is to have all the x values stored contiguously, so you can load multiple `x` values with a `movdqu` / `_mm_loadu_si128`.  If you're working with SIMD, choose the smallest element width that will support the range of values you need.  Using 64bit elements will cut your throughput in half, vs. 32bit elements.  Your code will process 128b at a time, and that's twice as many elements if they're half-width.