# struct of arrays and memory access patterns

Tags: c, arrays, struct, simd, cpu-cache

This is sort of a follow up to this original question with some new information added. See here for the first part if you're interested: [Struct of arrays, arrays of structs and memory usage pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421171/struct-of-arrays-arrays-of-structs-and-memory-usage-pattern)

It seems that there are quite a few problems with my first attempt at setting up struct of arrays for a simple class. Mainly being excess memory allocation for pointers and possible memory leaks from allocating those pointers from vec3_b in the previous question.

I though about how I could rearrange the data w/o using pointers, this requires me to first setup some const variable for the size of my data buckets, so no unbounded values like pointers but also reduces the amount of memory to something fixed.

```
    const size_t batch_size = 100;
    struct vec3_c
    {
    size_t x[batch_size];
    size_t y[batch_size];
    size_t z[batch_size];
    };

    struct vec3_c vec3_c(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, size_t index)
    {
        struct vec3_c v;
        v.x[index] = x;
        v.y[index] = y;
        v.z[index] = z;
        return v;
    }

        struct vec3_c vc3;        
        for(int i = 0; i < batch_size; i++)
        {
            vc3 = vec3_c(i+1, i*i, i*10, i);
            //printf("vec3c x:%zu, y:%zu, z:%zu\n",vc3.x[i], vc3.y[i], vc3.z[i]);
            printf("vec3c x:%p, y:%p, z:%p\n",(void*)&vc3.x[i], (void*)&vc3.y[i], (void*)&vc3.z[i]);
        }

      ---------------x-----------------|----------------y-----------------|----------------z-----------------|

0|      0x7fff57489f40 : 140734657765184 | 0x7fff5748a260 : 140734657765984 | 0x7fff5748a580 : 140734657766784
1|      0x7fff57489f48 : 140734657765192 | 0x7fff5748a268 : 140734657765992 | 0x7fff5748a588 : 140734657766792
2|      0x7fff57489f50 : 140734657765200 | 0x7fff5748a270 : 140734657766000 | 0x7fff5748a590 : 140734657766800
```

with this updated code I have to have a fixed bucket size so I set it to batch_size of 100 just for simple numbers. Fill up the vec3c with some data and did a similar test, this time it seems that each value is aligned in 8 byte chunks.

ex:

```
size of vec3      : 24 bytes
size of vec3a     : 24 bytes
size of vec3b     : 24 bytes
size of vec3c     : 2400 bytes
size of size_t    : 8 bytes
size of int       : 4 bytes
size of 16 int    : 64 bytes
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f40, y:0x7fff592d3260, z:0x7fff592d3580
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f48, y:0x7fff592d3268, z:0x7fff592d3588
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f50, y:0x7fff592d3270, z:0x7fff592d3590
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f58, y:0x7fff592d3278, z:0x7fff592d3598
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f60, y:0x7fff592d3280, z:0x7fff592d35a0
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f68, y:0x7fff592d3288, z:0x7fff592d35a8
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f70, y:0x7fff592d3290, z:0x7fff592d35b0
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f78, y:0x7fff592d3298, z:0x7fff592d35b8
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f80, y:0x7fff592d32a0, z:0x7fff592d35c0
vec3c x:0x7fff592d2f88, y:0x7fff592d32a8, z:0x7fff592d35c8
```

are all separated by 8 bytes.

That should get rid of the issues of memory leaks and the excess memory needed for the pointers.

with this being the new layout something like sizeof(vc3[0].x) would return 8 bytes.

back to the original questions:

1. Is my implementation of `struct vec3_c` the proper way to setup a struct of array?
2. with a vec_3c batch size of 100 it's showing 2400 bytes large but each individual element is only 8 bytes and properly aligned, so I could actually now fit 8 elements on 1 modern cpu cache line?
3. would transforming data passed to me in say a typical format of just arrays of structures outweigh the performance benefits of being in a cache friendly state and able to operate on multiple data points per instruction call? This is with the caveat that both points 1 and 2 are correct.

ex doing the dot product of two vectors:
that means I could get the dot product of 2 vec3_c per instruction cycle?

**edit**
one more question, would it be better to add the additional 8 bytes of data to make this struct a multiple of 32 bytes and maybe use that additional 8 bytes as scratch space or just leave it empty?

**edit**
It was pointed out to me that my initial initialization function was just making a mess of things. I updated it to this form:

```
struct vec3_c* vec3_c()
{
    struct vec3_c *v = (struct vec3_c*)malloc(sizeof(struct vec3_c));
    v->index = 0;
    return v;
}

struct vec3_c* v3 = vec3_c();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < batch_size; i++)
    {
        v3->x[i] = i + 1;
        v3->y[i] = i * i;
        v3->z[i] = i * 10;
        printf("index:%d\tvec3c x:%zu, y:%zu, z:%zu\n",i,v3->x[i], v3->y[i], v3->z[i]);
        printf("index:%zu\tvec3c x:%p, y:%p, z:%p\n",i,(void*)&v3->x[i], (void*)&v3->y[i], (void*)&v3->z[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am misinterpreting the whole problem, but it seems to me that you are using vc3 an v incorrectly: indeed, the function vec3_c allocates a local (uninitialized) "v", then sets SOME fields and returns a COPY OF v (whose fields contain unpredictable values, except for the "index" one). I see that in your example you are not actually interested on the content of  vc3, so what is the purpose of function vec3_c?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini my initial code sample had a few bugs that I sorted out over time. I would use this structure to batch process vec3 values something in like a stream processing or SIMD type instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to have *lots* of these xyz points and you want to be able to perform an action on all the x's at once, then it makes more sense to put all the x's together:

```
struct PointBatch {
    size_t x[batchsize];
    size_t y[batchsize];
    size_t z[batchsize];
}

// More efficient for things like
// - find the point with the largest X
// - find the sum of all the points as [xsum, ysum, zsum]
```

If you normally operate on the x, y, and z of single data points, then it makes more sense to put each point together as a struct.

```
struct Point {
    size_t x;
    size_t y;
    size_t z;
}

struct Point pointBatch[batchsize];

// Better for things like
// - plot all the points on a graph
// - determine which points satisfy the equation: x^2 + y^2 < z^2
```

**N.B.**
Note that where performance is *not* an issue, you will probably find that the `Point`/`pointBatch` approach makes your code easier to write and more readable as `struct PointBatch` gives you no convenient way to refer to or pass around a single point.

Comment: the data will most likely be passed to me in the form of struct A but to process it more efficiently in my algorithms i'll have to transform from A to B once and store B to process them in batches. I made reference to that in the original question asking about the transformation cost once upfront vs the batching for cache coherence and SIMD style processing.

Comment: Actually, if you need to run through all the points in sequence, a struct-of-arrays is MUCH better for SIMD.  The `x^2 + y^2 < z^2` example is a good case:  with SoA, you load a vector of `x`s, a vector of `y`s, and a vector of `z`s.  Square each, then add the x vector to the y vector.  Then `PCMPGT` the sum with the `z^2`, then `movmsk` or `ptest`.  With AoS, you have these oddly-packed sequences of x,y,z,x2 or w/e in your vectors, and it's horrible.  Hardware prefetchers can handle many streams in parallel.

Comment: thank you that's the direction that I am heading towards to to do SIMD type batch processing of the data. I'll first have to rotate them from AoS to SoA.

Comment: Be careful with just looping over a larger-than-cache buffer when doing the conversion.  The extra memory traffic will be bad.  Instead, work in smaller batches (convert maybe 64kiB of points if needed, then feed that to your vector routine).  This is called cache-blocking or tiling.

Comment: If your first comment was accurate, that you'll get the data passed in in `struct A` form, then you should leave them that way, and write any non-vector routines to access them in that format.  OTOH, if your earlier question, with crazy struct-of-pointers-to-single-elements is accurate, then yeah you need to convert.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one problem with this part of your code :

```
struct vec3_c vec3_c(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z, size_t index)
{
    struct vec3_c v;
    v.x[index] = x;
    v.y[index] = y;
    v.z[index] = z;
    return v;
}
```

You create a new `vec3_v` struct on the stack and return it. That means that each call will return a new struct with all elements uninitialized except `index` row.

And later when you do (100 times) `vc3 = vec3_c(i+1, i*i, i*10, i);`, you copy 300 values (size of the struct), 297 of which are not initialized : that's really unefficient and invokes Undefined Behaviour !

Comment: It's actually the caller that allocates space for the return value.  In the x86 and amd64 ABIs, the caller passes a pointer to this space.  (And the callee would have to run the constructor, if it wasn't already the constructor, so yeah, it would have to zero the parts it didn't write.  Or would it?  That code doesn't use an initializer that would require the untouched elements to be zeroed.  The returned `vec3_c` is uninitialized except for `v.*[index]`)  If you're lucky, the compiler could eliminate most of this after inlining that constructor.

Comment: @PeterCordes : of course you are true ! It is C and not C++ ... And it is explicit in 6.7.9 10 : *If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate*

Comment: Even if it was c++, with no zero-arg constructor, wouldn't it still be uninitialized?

Comment: @PeterCordes : In C++ I always use non default ctors to be sure that data is properly initialized. But the default ctor would not initialize anything either :-)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right, C++ won't let you instantiate something without args to the constructor if there IS no default constructor (and there's at least one non-default constructor).  Like what would happen if you compiled this code as C++.

Comment: you guys are actually right and I was doing too much in my initializer function. I will update the question with the new constructor which just malloc's a pointer to vec3 and returns it. Then I can fill in the data at a later point in the code. One thing that I noticed is that batch_size needs to be const but if I set batch_size greater than 1<<18 on my machine I get a Segmentation fault: 11, 1<<18 and lower and everything seems to be fine.